# groupby lambda function taking 2 column arguments

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, lambda, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
pd.DataFrame({
'building': ['house', 'tower', 'house', 'apt', 'apt'],
'material': ['wood', 'metal', 'brick', 'metal', 'metal'],
'size': [20, 100, 35, 5, 15]})
```

I am looking to write a groupby, lambda function, that looks something like this:

```
groupby('building').agg(
proportion_of_blue_area=('size', lambda x: sum(x) if x == 'metal' / sum(x))).reset_index()
```

The expected output I am looking for is the percentage of metal size out of the building's total size. I know the lambda function doesn't actually call the "material" column, I'm not sure where/how to include it. **I need this solved within the groupby.agg the way its shown**. Thank you.

Comment: How is this different from your last question?

Comment: I am taking in two columns and arguments for the lambda function to evaluate instead of just 1.

Comment: `groupby().agg()` doesn't bring information from one column to another. Perhaps you want `groupby().apply()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the `pd.transform` is the one you are missing:

```py
(
    pd.DataFrame({
        'building': ['house', 'tower', 'house', 'apt', 'apt'],
        'material': ['wood', 'metal', 'brick', 'metal', 'metal'],
        'size': [20, 100, 35, 5, 15]
    })
    .groupby(["building", "material"], as_index=False)
    .agg("sum")
    .assign(size=lambda df: df.groupby("building").transform(lambda x: x / x.sum()))
    .loc[lambda df: df.material == "metal"]
)

#   building material  size
# 0      apt    metal   1.0
# 3    tower    metal   1.0
```

NOTE : I have added a first `groupby-sum` because I have noticed two apt/metal combinations and guessed it was meant to be summed. It is optional.

Comment: Thank you @ClementWalter